# When applying `map` to a `Set` you sometimes want the result not to be a set but overlook this

Tags: scala

Or how to avoid accidental removal of duplicates when mapping a `Set`?

This is a mistake I'm doing very often. Look at the following code:

```
def countSubelements[A](sl: Set[List[A]]): Int = sl.map(_.size).sum
```

The function shall count the accumulated size of all the contained lists. The problem is that after mapping the lists to their lengths, the result is still a `Set` and all lists of size 1 are reduced to a single representative.

Is it just me having this problem? Is there something I can do to prevent this happening? I think I'd love to have two methods `mapToSet` and `mapToSeq` for `Set`. But there is no way to enforce this, and sometimes you don't locally notice that you are working with a `Set`.

Maybe it's even possible that you were writing code for a `Seq` and something changes in another class and the underlying object becomes a `Set`?

Maybe something like a best practise to not let this situation arise at all?

### Remote edits break my code

Imagine the following situation:

```
val totalEdges = graph.nodes.map(_.getEdges).map(_.size).sum / 2
```

You fetch a collection of `Node` objects from a graph, use them to get their adjacent edges and sum over them. This works if `graph.nodes` returns a `Seq`.

And it breaks if someone decides to make `Graph` return its nodes as a `Set`; without this code looking suspicious (at least not to me, do you expect every collection could possibly end up being a `Set`?) and without touching it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there will be many possible "gotcha's" if one expects a `Seq` and gets a `Set`. It's not a surprise that method implementations can depend on the type of the object and (with overloading) the arguments. With Scala implicits, the method can even depend on the *expected return type*.

A way to defend against surprises is to explicitly label types. For example, annotating methods with return types, even if it's not required. At least this way, if the type of `graph.nodes` is changed from `Seq` to `Set`, the programmer is aware that there's potential breakage.

For your specific issue, why not define your own`mapToSeq` method,

```
scala> def mapToSeq[A, B](t: Traversable[A])(f: A => B): Seq[B] =
           t.map(f)(collection.breakOut)
mapToSeq: [A, B](t: Traversable[A])(f: A => B)Seq[B]

scala> mapToSeq(Set(Seq(1), Seq(1,2)))(_.sum)
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 3)

scala> mapToSeq(Seq(Seq(1), Seq(1,2)))(_.sum)
res2: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 3)
```

The advantage of using `breakOut: CanBuildFrom` is that the conversion from a `Set` to a `Seq` has no additional overhead.

You can make use the [pimp my library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) to make `mapToSeq` appear to be part of the `Traversable` trait, inherited by `Seq` and `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds:

```
def countSubelements[A](sl: Set[List[A]]): Int = sl.toSeq.map(_.size).sum

def countSubelements[A](sl: Set[List[A]]): Int = sl.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.size)
```

Comment: Of course you can fix it. But I'm looking for something like best practises to not make the mistake at all.

Comment: @ziggystar - To not make the mistake at all, use folds instead of map/sum.  If you make heavy use of sets, you could institute this as a "best practice" (i.e. do it for all collections, so it doesn't matter which one you're using).  You actually _mean_ a fold, not a map/sum, given that you don't want the mapped set to actually be mapped as a set.

Comment: I disagree. sum is already implemented as a fold - it's fold(0)(_ + _). You can indeed write either of the above suggestion, but I think a better best practice is just "always use toSeq", because the first line above is much more natural. The second line is asymmetrical and thus less elegant, and even potentially less efficient in a context where the underlying collection is parallel - fold can be optimized better than foldLeft/foldRight in such a context.