# Scala Range contains(elem: Any) method

Tags: scala, scalac

Apparently `Range` has a method that checks if it contains a value of type Any. I understand that it is from `SeqLike`, but causes some problems.

For instance, i was matching hours from joda.DateTime:

```
DateTime.now match {
    case d if 0 to 12 contains d.hourOfDay() => ...
```

Here d.hourOfDay() returns DateTime.Property, not Int, but code still compiles, because of `contains(elem: Any)`. Is there any way to check for such calls at compile time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [pimp](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) `Range` to add a type-safer contains method:

```
class SafeRange( range: Range ) {
  def safeContains( i: Int ) = range contains i
}

object SafeRange {
  implicit def safer( range: Range ) = new SafeRange( range )
}
```

Import the implicit and call `safeContains` on any range instance:

```
scala> import SafeRange._
import SafeRange._

scala> (0 until 10) safeContains 3
res2: Boolean = true

scala> (0 until 10) safeContains 100
res3: Boolean = false

scala> (0 until 10) safeContains "foo"
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("foo")
 required: Int
          (0 until 10) safeContains
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Scalaz's typesafe equals (`===`) in conjunction with `exists` method on `TraversableOnce`.

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> 1 to 5 exists { _ === 2 }
res1: Boolean = true

scala> 1 to 5 exists { _ === "Hullo" }
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("Hullo")
 required: Int
       1 to 5 exists { _ === "Hullo" }
                             ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the scaladocs for Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) it looks like there's not a better Range method you could use. Your options seem to be

Use an explicit type signature:

```
 case d if 0 to 12 contains (d.hourOfDay(): Int) => ...
```

Make your own method:

```
 def containsInt(r: Range, i: Int) = ...
```

This seems to be a holdover from Java `equals` being pre-generics, and is only one of the inconveniences this fact causes for Scala.

Comment: Yeah... But maybe there should be some sort of compiler warning for calls to such methods. It seems wrong to have such runtime errors in a type-safe language.

Comment: I would love to have a plugin that generates more/better warnings. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @ziggystar I'm not aware of one. I'm not sure how the compiler could even tell this isn't what you want, short of deprecating the method (which might be the right solution, but it has other problems...)

Comment: @Owen There are other situations where I am unhappy with the std lib because it makes it easy to make a mistake. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040806/when-applying-map-to-a-set-you-sometimes-want-the-result-not-to-be-a-set-but