# Scala FlatMap provides wrong results

Tags: scala, flatten, flatmap

given a list of documents, I want to obtain the pairs that shares at least one token.
To do this I wrote the code below, that do that through an inverted index.

```
object TestFlatMap {
 case class Document(id : Int, tokens : List[String])

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val documents = List(
     Document(1, List("A", "B", "C", "D")),
     Document(2, List("A", "B", "E", "F", "G")),
     Document(3, List("E", "G", "H")),
     Document(4, List("A", "L", "M", "N"))
   )

   val expectedTokensIds = List(("A",1), ("A",2), ("A",4), ("B",1), ("B",2), ("C",1), ("D",1), ("E",2), ("E",3), ("F",2), ("G",2), ("G",3), ("H",3), ("L",4), ("M",4), ("N",4)) //Expected tokens - id tuples
   val expectedCouples = Set((1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)) //Expected resulting pairs


   /**
     * For each token returns the id of the documents that contains it
     * */
   val tokensIds = documents.flatMap{ document =>
     document.tokens.map{ token =>
       (token, document.id)
     }
   }

   //Check if the tuples are right
   assert(tokensIds.length == expectedTokensIds.length && tokensIds.intersect(expectedTokensIds).length == expectedTokensIds.length, "Error: tokens-ids not matches")

   //Group the documents by the token
   val docIdsByToken = tokensIds.groupBy(_._1).filter(_._2.size > 1)

   /**
     * For each group of documents generate the pairs
     * */
   val couples = docIdsByToken.map{ case (token, docs) =>
     docs.combinations(2).map{ c =>
       val d1 = c.head._2
       val d2 = c.last._2

       if(d1 < d2){
         (d1, d2)
       }
       else{
         (d2, d1)
       }
     }
   }.flatten.toSet


   /**
     * Same operation, but with flatMap
     * For each group of documents generate the pairs
     * */
   val couples1 = docIdsByToken.flatMap{ case (token, docs) =>
     docs.combinations(2).map{ c =>
       val d1 = c.head._2
       val d2 = c.last._2

       if(d1 < d2){
         (d1, d2)
       }
       else{
         (d2, d1)
       }
     }
   }.toSet

   //The results obtained with flatten pass the test
   assert(couples.size == expectedCouples.size && couples.intersect(expectedCouples).size == expectedCouples.size, "Error: couples not matches")
   //The results obtained with flatMap do not pass the test: they are wrong
   assert(couples1.size == expectedCouples.size && couples1.intersect(expectedCouples).size == expectedCouples.size, "Error: couples1 not matches")
}
```

The problem is that the flatMap that should generates the final results does not works properly, it only returns two couples: (2,3) and (1,2).
I do not understand why it does not works, moreover IntelliJ suggests me to use flatMap instead of use map an then flatten.

Someone is able to explain me where the problem is? Because I cannot figure out, I also had this problem in past.

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an excellent example that demonstrates that all the nice monad laws do not necessarily hold if you switch between different types of collections during the `map`/`flatMap`/`flatten`.

---

You must convert the `Map` to `List`, so that keys are not overridden repeatedly while you are constructing another `Map` as an intermediate result, because a `Map` will override keys, instead of collecting all pairs:

```
val couples1 = docIdsByToken.toList.flatMap{ case (token, docs) =>
  docs.combinations(2).map{ c =>
    val d1 = c.head._2
    val d2 = c.last._2

    if(d1 < d2){
      (d1, d2)
    }
    else{
      (d2, d1)
    }
  }
}.toSet
```

Here is a much shorter version that demonstrates the same problem:

```
val m = Map("A" -> (2, 1), "B" -> (2, 3))
val s = m.flatMap{ case (k, v) => List(v) }.toSet
println(s)
```

Instead of `Set((2, 1), (2, 3))`, it will produce `Set((2, 3))`, because
after the `flatMap` and before the `toSet` the intermediate result *is a new `Map`*, and this map can hold only *one value* for `key = 2`.

The difference to the first version is that after `map`, you obtain something like an `Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]]`, which is not a `Map`, and therefore cannot lose/override any keys.

Comment: `token` is never referenced. This makes more sense: `val couples1 = docIdsByToken.values.flatMap{ docs =>` . . .

Comment: @jwvh I've copied a piece of code that has been compiled, tested (at least superficially, by visual examination of the output), and that passed all assertions supplied by the OP. The token is not supposed to be referenced, it acts only as a glue between the numbers. Once the pairs of numbers are found, the string tokens can be discarded. It should be replaced by and underscore, though. I kept it to retain as much of the original code as possible.

Comment: This is one of the worst "features" of Scala's current collection library. I had so many bugs because of mapping `Set` and `Map`.

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040806/when-applying-map-to-a-set-you-sometimes-want-the-result-not-to-be-a-set-but) I once asked on this issue.

Comment: @ziggystar good question, but for some reason I'm not impressed with the workarounds. Hoped for something more systematic, to be honest :]

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have to agree with you, sadly. I think the new collections library will fix it.