# Using value to find key in mutable map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

We have the case class Item and a categoryMap shown as follows:

`case class Item(id: Int, name: String)`

`val categoryMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[CategoryId: Int, List[Item]]()`

How can we find the `CategoryId`-key in 'categoryMap' if we have the `id` of `Item`?

Comment: The title of your question and *your actual question* are two different things. Which one do you need?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I couldn't find a revision in which the title of the question was too different from the body. The OP has a `Map` from categories ("keys") to lists of items ("values"), and now wants to find the category ("key") given an `id` of an `Item` ("value"). Seems rather like a valid and unambiguous question to me. Could the question be made clearer if it didn't use the word "value" in the sense it is used now?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You and Stefano provided completely different answers to the same question. I think this arises from the ambiguity of having an `Int` field for the key, which our brain probably automagically makes the correlation for us between the `Id` field inside the `Item` case class and that `Int`, since they also align type wise. That's why I think the question should be clarified.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah, right... Two different answers, indeed. I think one might try to carefully insert a few type-aliases into the code, to clarify the distinction between Item-Ids and categories. Otherwise it's all Int-Int-Int everywhere... Maybe the OP should update it, because I can also not be 100% sure whether I understood it correctly.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov We have the ID of an Item in the List of items i.e. the value in the map and I want to get the key of the same. Does that add clarity to the question?

Comment: Can an `id` be found in more than one category? In other words, might we need more than one key to find every reference for a given `id`?

Comment: @jwvh An Item `id` can be only inside single category `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build another map from `id` to category (some irrelevant fields of `Item` omitted):

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)

val categoryMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,List[Item]](
  2 -> List(Item(42, "foo"), Item(34, "bar")),
  3 -> List(Item(9824, "baz"), Item(9836, "oofzab"))
)

val itemIdToCategory = (for {
  (k, v) <- categoryMap.toList
  id <- v.map(_.id)
} yield (id, k)).toMap

println(itemIdToCategory(42))
println(itemIdToCategory(34))
println(itemIdToCategory(9824))
println(itemIdToCategory(9836))
```

Prints: `2 2 3 3`.

Comment: `.toList` not needed.

Comment: @Andrey If I try to run in **SCALA worksheet**  I'm getting :
`defined class Item

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
 at com.src.A$A13$A$A13$Item.<init>(teset.sc:1)
 at com.src.A$A13$A$A13.categoryMap$lzycompute(teset.sc:4)
 at com.src.A$A13$A$A13.categoryMap(teset.sc:3)
 at com.src.A$A13$A$A13.get$$instance$$categoryMap(teset.sc:3)
 at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(teset.sc:24)
`


**Its working fine if we enter REPL mode, Why so? Any idea?**

Comment: @AdityaChopra if it cannot find even `scala.Product.$init$`, then something is severely not-ok with your "worksheet" (whatever it is). The above code runs if interpreted as script with `scala` version 2.12.4

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Oh! Okay, Thank you! :)

Comment: @jwvh I'm to 99.9999% sure that you are right. But because of [the funny things that can happen to `Map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127313/scala-flatmap-provides-wrong-results/49127726#49127726), and because I didn't have time to write test cases for this little snippet, I was hesitant to remove `toList` from the code. That's because in contrast to `Map`, a `List` is actually a proper monad, so I don't have to think about what happens with all the CBF's between the `flatMap` and the `map`-lines implicitly present in the `for`-comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)
val item1 = List(Item(1001, "HP"), Item(1002, "Dell"))
val item2 = List(Item(1003, "Fish1"), Item(1004, "Fish2"))
val categoryMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, List[Item]](100 -> item1,101 -> item2)
val catmap = categoryMap.flatMap { case (key, value) => value.map(_.id -> key) }
println(catmap.getOrElse(1001, null))
```

> Output : 100